# Should the noun "community" be capitalised in the following example?

Tags: capitalization, greetings

When posting questions on forums such as this one, I usually start with a simple greeting such as "Dear community" and I would like to ask whether "community" should be capitalised in this example. From what I know, it should only be capitalised when it is used as a name of an association. However, I also came across examples such as "Dear Community Member" where both community and member are capitalised. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not an official named entity, it does not need capitalising, however in an informal address such as that which you're proposing, I would say it comes down to personal choice. I would probably go with 'Dear Community,' myself.